# django 管理者作成時にパスワードが入力できません

Tags: python, django

`python manage.py createsuperuser` でADMIN追加をしようとしたのですが、
英語も数字も入力ができません。他の項目は入力できています。
初歩的な質問ですみません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

画像のようなテキストベースの環境でパスワードを設定する場合、大抵は **セキュリティ上の理由** で入力した文字を画面に表示しませんが、実際には入力できています。

打ち間違えがないようにゆっくりと入力した後、Enterを押してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決できました。